# How to stop the counter from increasing

Tags: python

The `step1` and `step2` counter becomes zero after every recursion. What can I do to stop them from getting zero?

```
def checknumber(num):
    a = []
    a = list(num)
    print(a)
    for iter in range(0,len(a)):
        if int(a[iter])%2 ==0:
            print(a[iter])
            print("yes")
            return 6
        else :
            print("No")
            return 7
def inc(number,step1=0):
    number1 = int(number)
    number1=number1 + 1
    print(step1)
    step1= step1+1
    print(step1)
    if(checknumber(str(number1))==7):
        inc(number1)
    else:
        return step1
```

Comment: If you don't want the default value, pass the value you **do** want when you call the function again: `inc(number1, step1 = newValue)`

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and make sure your code is properly formatted, and consider adding more detail to it. Thank you.

Comment: I do not see any `step2` variable in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code as below:

```
def checknumber(num):
    a = []
    a = list(num)
    print(a)
    for iter in range(0,len(a)):
        if int(a[iter])%2 ==0:
            print(a[iter])
            print("yes")
            return 6
        else :
            print("No")
            return 7
def inc(number,step1=0):
       number1 = int(number)
       number1=number1 + 1
       print(step1)
       step1= step1+1
       print(step1)
       if(checknumber(str(number1))==7):
           inc(number1,step1)
       else:
           return step1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function definition you set `step1` to have a default value of zero.
Then every time you called the function you didn't send a parameter for `step1`, which the compiler translates as if you sent a `0`.

If you want to stop this from happening: add a second parameter with current value of `step1` every time you call the function.